# How do you store big objects using NSUserDefaults efficiently?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsobject

How do you store big objects using NSUserDefaults efficiently? Any help will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't. `NSUserDefaults` is not meant for storing anything but little bits of info. Use a plist file, some other file, or a database.

Comment: So storing an array of objects consisting of NSNumbers is to much data?  And i have considered using a database, but i wanted to keep the information locally stored.  Could you please elaborate on what a pList file would entail?  It'd be really appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is not for data. Simply write the `NSArray` to a file (see the docs for `NSArray`). That will create a plist with the numbers. BTW - a database would be local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using `NSUserDefaults` for anything large that you want to store.  You are better off either writing the data to a file or storing it in a db such as core data.  Depending on what you are trying to store one of these can make more sense then the other.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

You can look at `NSKeyedArchiver` or `NSFileManager` plus whatever type of data you are working with for more information about how to write it to a file.